# Meaning of [-1,1][+!!boolean_var]

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain the purpose of double-negating the `reverse` var in the below code?

```
return function (a,b) {
   var A = key(a), B = key(b);
   return ((A < B) ? -1 :
           (A > B) ? +1 : 0)) * [-1,1][+!!reverse];                  
}
```

The way I understand it, the purpose is to pick the proper index from the `[-1,1]` array  to then use it in the multiplication but it seems to me that `[-1,1][+!!reverse];` could be safely replaced by `[-1,1][+reverse];`

Am I wrong? What do you gain or prevent by double-negating `reverse` there?

I saw the above code on [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/979325/345490)

Comment: That is awesome, curious to see an answer on this one

Comment: It changes the value of reverse to a boolean.

[What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: I would use `(reverse? 1 : -1)` instead of `[-1,1][+!!reverse]`, IMO is just more clear, it's cheaper, it doesn't need an array object and accessing an index, and even the boolean conversion is implicitly made by the conditional operator...

Comment: @CMS I agree, if the whole purpose is just to multiply by 1 when true; otherwise by -1, `reverse?1:-1` is clearer and cheaper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest answer is probably a counter-example:

```
+undefined //NaN
+!!undefined // 0
```

since contents of [] are generally converted to strings, [NaN] will attempt to access the property called "NaN" from the array, which does not exist and will return undefined:

```
[1,-1][+undefined]
[1,-1][NaN]
[1,-1]["NaN"]
undefined
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel that I need to run and buy a Javascript book ASAP :$

Answer (score 4):

Double negating simply ensures that we have a proper boolean. Since reverse could be anything,  double negating it invokes JavaScript's "falsy" conversions. So, for example:

```
!!"hello" // true
!!"" // false
!!1 // true
!!some_undefined_var // false
```

Answer (score 2):

The `!!` converts the value to a boolean.  This is needed if `reverse` isn't a boolean to start off with.

Consider: `+!!"hi"`.  This is `1`, but `+"hi"` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

the double-negation basically casts reverse as a boolean, and then + will cast that boolean as an int.

so, if reverse is possibly:
"yes", "no", "", true, false, 0,1,2, undefined

the double negation will make
"yes" -> true
"no" -> true
"" -> false
true -> true
false -> false
undefined -> false

then, the + will convert trues to 1, and falses to 0, so that it can be used as an array index.